# How to hide/show buttons c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to be able to make a program. It's a program for a pizza from.
I have two buttons on the side (Pizza and subs)
When I click the pizza button, i want it to show the rest of the buttons to add a small pizza,medium pizza and large pizza.
If i click the subs button however the pizza buttons go away and instead the subs button appear to add subs.. etc

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried Button's Visible property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.button.visible.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question as asked, you should put all the controls for Pizza in to one GroupBox and the controls for Subs in to another GroupBox. Place both GroupBoxes at the same location and then on the click of the radio button, make one visible and the other not visible.

That said, you should consider the user experience. More intuitive than a form changing based on radio buttons (and even easier to code) would be a TabControl with tabs of "Pizza" and "Subs".

TabControl:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Comment: Yes, that IS better.  And the tab control can be modified to look like it's using buttons instead of the standard tabs.  Good call!

Comment: Claudiu: if it was exactly what you were looking for, click the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes...

Handle the `Click` event and, in the handler, set the `Visible` property of your buttons/UserControl/whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the Visible property of the buttons to true or false as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can set NameOfControl.visible = false on any controls you want to disappear.

Setting NameOfControl.visible = true shows them again.

Answer (score 1):

select button fields and open filds property now select event from top of property windos and then select event as mouse click event and double click on that after that u will able to see in view code mouse click event now write the code.

button1.Visible = true;